# Selected item not showing in DropdownButton in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I need your help. I'm making a `DropdownButton` and I'm facing the following problem - I can't see the items that are selected in the `DropdownMenuItems`. I do not understand what the problem is that nothing is displayed. I'm using the [getwidget][1] package it's a `GFCheckboxListTile` widget - which just adds a checkbox. Please tell me how can I fix this error?

**dropdown**

```
import 'package:dropdown_button2/dropdown_button2.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/svg.dart';
import 'package:getwidget/getwidget.dart';
import 'package:joyn/constants/constants.dart' as constants;

class DropdownWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  List<String> items;
  SvgPicture? icon;
  double width;

  DropdownWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.items,
    required this.icon,
    required this.width,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<DropdownWidget> createState() => _DropdownWidgetState();
}

class _DropdownWidgetState extends State<DropdownWidget> {
  String? selectedValue;
  bool selected = false;

  final List _selectedTitles = [];
  final List _selectedTitlesIndex = [];

  final GFCheckboxType type = GFCheckboxType.basic;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (widget.items.isNotEmpty) {
      _selectedTitles.add(widget.items[1]);
    }
  }

  void _onItemSelect(bool selected, int index) {
    if (selected == true) {
      setState(() {
        _selectedTitles.add(widget.items[index]);
        _selectedTitlesIndex.add(index);
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _selectedTitles.remove(widget.items[index]);
        _selectedTitlesIndex.remove(index);
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: widget.width,
      child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
        child: DropdownButton(
          items: List.generate(
            widget.items.length,
            (index) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
              value: widget.items[index],
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border(
                    bottom: BorderSide(
                      color: constants.Colors.white.withOpacity(0.1),
                      width: 1,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                child: GFCheckboxListTile(
                  value: _selectedTitles.contains(widget.items[index]),
                  onChanged: (bool selected) {
                    _onItemSelect(selected, index);
                  },
                  selected: selected,
                  title: Text(
                    widget.items[index],
                    style: constants.Styles.smallTextStyleWhite,
                  ),
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 14, bottom: 13),
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 12, left: 2),
                  size: 22,
                  activeBgColor: constants.Colors.greyCheckbox,
                  activeBorderColor: Colors.red,
                  inactiveBgColor: constants.Colors.greyCheckbox,
                  activeIcon: SvgPicture.asset(constants.Assets.checkboxIcon),
                  inactiveBorderColor: constants.Colors.greyXMiddle,
                  type: type,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          value: selectedValue,
          onChanged: (value) {
            setState(() {
              selectedValue = value as String;
            });
          },
          icon: SvgPicture.asset(constants.Assets.arrowDropdown),
          iconSize: 21,
          itemHeight: 66,
          selectedItemBuilder: (context) {
            return _selectedTitles.map(
              (item) {
                return Row(
                  children: [
                    widget.icon ?? const SizedBox(),
                    const SizedBox(width: 8),
                    Text(
                      item,
                      style: constants.Styles.bigBookTextStyleWhite,
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              },
            ).toList();
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you simplify the widget, there are some widgets are missing ?

Comment: Yes, I can simplify the widget. I just don't know what needs to be fixed.

Comment: Widgets like `GFCheckboxListTile` , `DropdownButton2`  are missing

Comment: These are third party packages but I can replace DropdownButton2 with a regular DropdownButton

Comment: I removed DropdownButton2 and replaced it with a regular DropdownButton (code updated in question). And GFCheckboxListTile is just a widget that adds a checkbox

Comment: Updated the question. I will be grateful if you help me solve the problem, because I have been sitting on the problem for a long time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the UI is need to update on `DropdownMenuItem` you can wrap `GFCheckboxListTile` with `StatefulBuilder`.

```dart
child: Container(
  child: StatefulBuilder(
    builder: (context, setStateSB) => GFCheckboxListTile(
      value: _selectedTitles.contains(widget.items[index]),
      onChanged: (bool selected) {
        _onItemSelect(selected, index);
        setStateSB(() {}); /// we are using StatefulBuilder's setState

       ///add your logic then 
  setState(() {
    selectedValue = widget.items[index];
  });
      },
```

`DropdownMenuItem` ontap is outSide the `GFCheckboxListTile` therefore `onChanged` is not calling.  I am using `onChanged` from `GFCheckboxListTile` to update the `selectedValue`.

[image]

Comment: Does the rest of the code need to be changed?

Comment: no , just wrap with `StatefulBuilder` and use its setState

Comment: Oh, I understand, by the way, thank you very much for helping to solve this problem, I also did not know how to do it!

Comment: Now I can immediately observe the selected items. And another question, my selected element is not shown in my dropdownbutton (title), why is it not displayed there?

Comment: There are few cases like this, where widget are separated on from current context[materialApp], we use `StatefulBuilder` or any state property update this. it can happen on dialog too. You can inspect the widget tree.

Comment: I mean here https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7eci.jpg , when the dropdown is closed, but I still don't see the element that is selected, I don't understand why

Comment: And how can you fix it?